# Is there a reward for earning all of the gold medals in time attack mode?

Tags: donkey-kong-country-returns

In *Donkey Kong Country Returns*, after beating a level, you unlock Time Attack mode, where you have to beat the level within certain time thresholds to earn gold, silver or bronze medals.  Earning gold and silver medas is *insanely hard*, requiring near-perfection.

Do I get anything by earning all gold medals as opposed to just earning any medal?

Comment: Do ulcers and high blood pressure count?

Comment: @Chad lol. What a reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After completing world 1, *Jungle*, I went back to find all the puzzle pieces and K•O•N•G letters, and earn a time-attack medal in all the levels.  When I found all puzzle pieces and letters in world 1, but before I earned time-attack medals on every level, the hidden 1-K *Platform Panic* level unlocked/appeared.

This leads me to believe that **you don't get anything for earning *any* time-attack medals**.

Comment: Actually, only getting the K-O-N-G letters is required to open up the -K levels. The puzzle pieces (as far as I can tell) just open up items in the galleries.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is anything to unlock after you get them. Like Chad said: "Only ulcers and high blood pressure".

Did you know there is a Shiny Gold Medal? You get that if you finish in the *fastest time possible*! And I thought just getting the plain old gold medal was hard… I even asked a Nintendo Representative and all he told me is "Just keep playing and see for yourself." I hope it has a payoff in the end after all that hard work. And I know you have to be lucky to be able to land a hit on some of the bosses, which makes it hard.