# Is there any point in collecting puzzle pieces in Donkey Kong Country Returns?

Tags: donkey-kong-country-returns

This is very similar to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11605/reward-for-earning-all-gold-medals-for-time-attacks-in-donkey-kong-country-return), except mine is about puzzle pieces (although I'm curious for a more satisfying answer to that question as well).

Does anyone know if there are rewards (other than getting image gallery or music gallery stuff updated) for collecting all the puzzle pieces? Also, what about beating levels in Mirror Mode or (like the other question) Time Trials?

Comment: Well... saying as how in the question you linked, the author mentions a bonus level unlocked after collecting the puzzle pieces (in addition to the kong letters)...

Comment: I've completed all the levels with KONG, and I know of the bonus levels from that. His answer doesn't seem too sure of what caused the bonus level in world 1 (which was from him collecting all the KONG pieces, I know it has nothing to do with the puzzle pieces).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually, collecting all the puzzle pieces will give you mirror mode. All the levels in reverse, no diddy, and dk only has one heart. Good luck with that one!

Comment: What!? That's insane. Oh if only I still had this game

Comment: @Sarah do you have any source about this ?

Comment: I was rather hasty in my accepting of this question and I have not tested it for myself. Could someone please (dis)prove this?

Comment: I owe the game and can confirm this is incorrect and @Macha's answer is correct. Mirror Mode is earned by completing the Golden Temple level. This level can only be played after beating the last boss and clearing all the temple levels within worlds 1-8, which are in turn unlocked by collecting all the KONG letters in their respective worlds. The puzzle pieces have nothing to do with obtaining Mirror Mode.

Answer (score 6):

No there is not. The [extra gallery items are the only reward](http://www.mariowiki.com/Puzzle_Piece_(Donkey_Kong_Country_Returns)).

Comment: What a disappointment! Oh well, the extra levels from KONG were worth it.

Answer (score 1):

The bonus levels are for rare orb balls. If you have all of them you can open the door of the golden temple.

You get the golden temple if you kill the endboss.

You get the bonus level if you have all of the kong letters in every world.